# emscripten: C functions not "ready" when called asynchronously in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, emscripten

I've compiled a C library with Emscripten and written JS that interacts with it correctly in an interactive Node.js shell:

```js
// script compiled by Emscripten
const _smaz = require("./_smaz");
var out_heap = _smaz['_malloc'](encoded.length * 8);
...
```

However, the `_malloc` fails when the function is called immediately within my app:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Object.a._malloc
```

Even adding a 100ms `setTimeout` solves the problem. Looks like the compiled Emscripten stuff loads asynchronously and functions can't be used immediately.

What's the correct way to handle this? The Emscripten [docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#faq-when-safe-to-call-compiled-functions) suggest adding a `Module['onRuntimeInitialized']` function once my "page" is loaded, but I'm not sure where that should go in a server-side Node.js app or whether it applies at all.

Here's how I'm compiling:

```
emcc smaz.c -O2 -o _smaz.js --closure 1 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_smaz_compress', '_smaz_decompress']" -s 'EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=["ccall", "cwrap"]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there are two `emcc` compiler options to disable the asynchronous startup/loading behaviour: `-s BINARYEN_ASYNC_COMPILATION=0` and `-s SINGLE_FILE=1`. This solves the problem for me.

From the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/5352#issuecomment-312384604):

> In general emscripten tries to do startup asynchronously for wasm,
>   because it's what browsers can best optimize, and worse, Chrome
>   currently has a limitation on the size of synchronous compilations
>   (hopefully will be fixed soon). But you can force sync compilation
>   with `-s BINARYEN_ASYNC_COMPILATION=0`.
>
> That still leaves fetching the wasm binary file. By default we fetch
>   it asynchronously, but if you have a way to get it yourself before,
>   you can set it on `Module['wasmBinary']` and we will just use that
>   synchronously. Alternatively, #5296 will add an option to embed that
>   file, making it available synchronously.